# Sails.js Viewing information from API

Tags: sails.js

I just started taking interest in Sails.JS
and I'm following a educational guide on it by Traversy Media. In this guide everything goes well for me until he generates an API where he accesses it through `localhost:1337/articles`.
I can't access this file only getting a 404 page, so I went searching on the internet for help. I found out I needed to add `/articles` to `config/routes.js` but i haven't figured out what to place in the `action` part.
At [10:36](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmjiDC_JUt4) in the Traversy Sails.JS tutorial, it shows the part I'm unable to browse to.
Is anyone able to help? Thanks in advance.

`ArticlesController.js` file is default

My `routes.js` :

```
    module.exports.routes = {


      'GET /':                   { action: 'view-homepage-or-redirect' },
      'GET /welcome':            { action: 'dashboard/view-welcome' },
      'GET /articles':           { action: 'view-Articles' },

      'GET /faq':                { view:   'pages/faq' },
      'GET /legal/terms':        { view:   'pages/legal/terms' },
      'GET /legal/privacy':      { view:   'pages/legal/privacy' },
      'GET /contact':            { view:   'pages/contact' },

      'GET /signup':             { action: 'entrance/view-signup' },
      'GET /email/confirm':      { action: 'entrance/confirm-email' },
      'GET /email/confirmed':    { view:   'pages/entrance/confirmed-email' },

      'GET /login':              { action: 'entrance/view-login' },
      'GET /password/forgot':    { action: 'entrance/view-forgot-password' },
      'GET /password/new':       { action: 'entrance/view-new-password' },

      'GET /account':            { action: 'account/view-account-overview' },
      'GET /account/password':   { action: 'account/view-edit-password' },
      'GET /account/profile':    { action: 'account/view-edit-profile' },


      '/api/v1/account/logout':                              { action: 'account/logout' },
      'PUT   /api/v1/account/update-password':               { action: 'account/update-password' },
      'PUT   /api/v1/account/update-profile':                { action: 'account/update-profile' },
      'PUT   /api/v1/account/update-billing-card':           { action: 'account/update-billing-card' },
      'PUT   /api/v1/entrance/login':                        { action: 'entrance/login' },
      'POST  /api/v1/entrance/signup':                       { action: 'entrance/signup' },
      'POST  /api/v1/entrance/send-password-recovery-email': { action: 'entrance/send-password-recovery-email' },
      'POST  /api/v1/entrance/update-password-and-login':    { action: 'entrance/update-password-and-login' },
      'POST  /api/v1/deliver-contact-form-message':          { action: 'deliver-contact-form-message' },


      '/terms':                   '/legal/terms',
      '/logout':                  '/api/v1/account/logout',

    };

Blueprints is also default
```

Comment: Do you have Articles controller? Please post its code, also please post config/blueprints.js and config/routes.js (better without comments)

Comment: Yes i have a ArticlesController

Comment: also please check, that you are using the same version on sails as in video. Latest version is 1, but video is about 0.12

Comment: Just noticed that aswell. but im still confused on how i need to access the API

Answer (score 0):

If you have in

config/blueprints.js

```
module.exports.blueprints = {
  actions: true,
  rest: false,
  shortcuts: true,
};
```

and ArticleController and some action (method) there, eg

```
module.exports = {
  hello: function(req, res) {
    return res.json('ok');
  }
}
```

You should be able to see 'ok' by url `localhost:1337/Article/hello`

Comment: still getting the 404

Comment: yeah they all work, its just the articles one that doesnt work,

Comment: i use nodemon to check for any changes.
I tried sails lift and nodemon app.js already

Comment: If you say, that other routes ok, that means that it is something about controller or action in it

Comment: i just need to be able to see the articles in the database

Comment: And i cant seem to find up to date guides

Comment: i have installed sails test project, and i see that '/articles' is not default route, so, you have added it manually... so i recommend you to use sails 0.12 as in video, to not to stuck on such trifles, till you would not get enough experience to achive it